# How to customize color for IconFont with Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to change color to white for IconFont component in Ant Design, But It's not effect.
Here is my code:

```
import React from "react"
import Icon, { createFromIconfontCN } from '@ant-design/icons'

const IconFont = createFromIconfontCN({
  scriptUrl: [
    '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_1920998_alrdzny2zo.js'
  ],
});

export default function Front() {
  return (
    <>
      <IconFont type="iconcart-add" style={{ color: '#fff', fill: '#fff'}}></IconFont>
    </>
  )
}
```

Please show me the way for customize color for this Item.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at https://ant.design/components/icon/

The properties theme, component and twoToneColor were added in 3.9.0. The best practice is to pass the property theme to every  component.

```
import { MessageOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

<MessageOutlined style={{ fontSize: '16px', color: '#08c' }} />;
```

All the icons will render to . You can still set style and className for size and color of icons.

```
<Icon type="message" style={{ fontSize: '16px', color: '#08c' }} theme="outlined" />
```

Comment: how to change color of **IconFont** component ? Could you make it more clearly ?